# How can I parse a massive HTTPS accessible XML file (with Java & Xerces) without storing it locally?

Tags: java, https, network-programming

While using some java code to download a process a very large XML file, I'm occasionally seeing errors like this.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[205648765,55]
Message: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
```

I imagine what's happening there is that the web server is deciding to kill connections which have been open longer than X hrs (it's a very big xml file), which obviously gives me a truncated stream, and hence a parser error.

How can I avoid this problem *without* fetching the entire file with something that can retry like wget? (imagine the file might be larger than the local disk for example).

Note - I can see that the server supports Range requests, so it seems like a possible solution is to have an InputStream implementation which catches the error, opens a new connections starting from the last byte it got, and continues on. Alternately, perhaps there's a way I'm not aware of to give the XML parser chunks of the file to work with rather than an InputStream.

Comment: Hmmm, two off-topic close votes out of 5 views...I guess because I'm asking for a library recommendation? Maybe I should rephrase it to ask for the implementation, and wait for someone to say 'Don't write yourself, use XYZ!' :)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254394/797 - Hmmm, ok, so maybe just "How should I parse a massive XML file (accessible via HTTPS) using Xerces without having to store the entire thing locally first?"...Probably too late to save this from the -2 it's on not anyway I guess...

Comment: You're asklng how to parse an XML file online that takes too long to send and parse online. Surely you understand that this is a contradiction in terms?

Comment: Well, assuming the server supports the Range header (it does), it's possible to fetch it in multiple requests, the trouble is, you can't easily have the XML parser handle multiple chunks (AFAIK). If there were some simple way to present a consistent InputStream which opened new connections to resume under the hood, that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any better answer, here's the hacked-up, untested, first-cut-version of a solution.

If there's some well tested version of the same concept out there, I'd still love to know about it.

```
package httpstreamresumer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

public class ResumingHttpStream extends InputStream {

    private long lastByte = -1;
    private String url;
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    private InputStream currentStream;

    public ResumingHttpStream(HttpClient httpClient, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        this.url = url;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        rebuildCurrentStream();
    }

    private void rebuildCurrentStream() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response;
        if (lastByte > 0) {
            httpRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Range", "bytes=" + (lastByte + 1) + "-"));

            response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 206) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expected 206 response code, but got " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() +" - Looks like the server doen't support Range requests");
            }
        } else {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);            
        }

        currentStream = response.getEntity().getContent();        
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int nextByte;
        try {
            nextByte = currentStream.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            rebuildCurrentStream();
            nextByte = currentStream.read();
            // If we fail twice without progressing, we probably need to give up
        }
        lastByte++;
        return nextByte;
    }

}
```